# How Can I Launch The App-store App Directly from my Application

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store

I want to place a button or a link in my app with which the user can start the app-store and buy my app if the app is in trial mode.

I can not find any relavant Information on this. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN documentation: [Creating links with the Windows Store protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh974767.aspx). Alternatively, the URI for the app in the store can be accessed using the [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LinkUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.linkuri) property.

You can then open a link to your app in the store using [Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh701480).