# Linking to apps in Windows Store

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I have created a few apps for the Windows Store and wish to provide a link in my About Page such that users can go straight to the download page of my other apps in the windows 8 store thereby facilitating easy lookup of my apps. Any idea how to do this ?  I am using HTML5/Javascript.

Comment: Related to the following question http://stackoverflow.com/q/12342728/1656796

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use ms-windows-store protocol, I did that by looking at store web page preview, in my case :

http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/hr-HR/app/coolinarika/b44b0383-dc60-430c-9461-58b2ada70042

and if you look at the source that url is constructed like this :

> ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=

and then application ID is added, my case is this :

> ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=WebMarketing.Coolinarika_tp6yaakah33yj

try to copy / paste link above into IE and it will open windows store with our app.

And here is a official way to do it :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974767.aspx

Answer (score 0):

here you can find a description how to link to the store from within your app:

http://www.win8tutorial.net/windows-store/link-programmatically-to-store/

Greetings

Christian